# Mean of all predictions in emmeans

Tags: mean, lm, lme4, emmeans

I am having trouble using emmeans to evaluate mean (or weighted mean) of all the predictions. For example, a mixed model:

```
library(emmeans)
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(mpg ~ 1 + wt + (1|cyl),data=mtcars)
```

Fixed effects "wt" is successful:

```
emmeans(m1,specs="wt")
   wt emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 3.22   20.2 1.71 1.83     12.1     28.3
```

However, to calculate the mean of predictions, the following previously worked (~ 12 months ago), but now fails:

```
emmeans(m1,specs="1")
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ".wgt.", value = 1) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

The same error occurs for simple linear models. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I was using the current version of emmeans (1.4.8) when I had the troubles described in the question. However, I may actually have been using emmeans 1.4.6 (please see comment by Russ Lenth below). I reverted back to emmeans v1.4.3 and the code worked. I then updated to the current version of emmeans (1.4.8) and the code continued to work. Most likely the cause was my use of emmeans 1.4.6, which had a known bug. Please see [this github entry](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/206) for more information.

Comment: I wonder if you had 1.4.6 before. There was a glitch in there for a little while.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment @RussLenth! it is quite possible I actually did have 1.4.6 when I came across the bug, even though I thought I had 1.4.8. I do not think I carefully checked my current version of emmeans before reverting back to 1.4.3 and then updating to 1.4.8.